# Windows 10 driver removed during upgrade

Tags: windows-10, command-line, drivers, powershell, automation

At our organisation we have a custom device for which the supplier of the device provides a driver. The problem is that the INF file that we're supposed to use for installation does not contain the hardware ID of the device. However by using device manager you can force to install the driver anyway (the supplier provides instructions to do so). However since Windows 10, drivers that are installed this way are automatically removed when performing an upgrade to, for instance, the April 2018 update. So every time Windows has a large update, we have to reinstall the driver on each of our computers manually.

I have looked into installing drivers using DevCon.exe, yet since the hardware ID is not found in the INF file, the installation fails.

I also tried to add the hardware ID to the INF file, however then the WHQL signing is no longer valid.

Since installing the driver manually is possible and works as expected. Is there another way to automate the installation of a driver for a device with a hardware ID that is not found in the INF-file? Or maybe is there a way to prevent Windows 10 from removing this specific driver during upgrades (other hardware drivers should still be updated automatically)?

Comment: Real solution is to have the hardware supplier provide a windows 10 compatible driver.

Comment: Next time it does it look in device manager to see if you can roll back the driver to a point before it was removed.

Comment: Run a Powershell script on boot that checks for the driver's existence, and if not found, installs it.